# Parsing Data by Event in Python

Tags: python, events, formatting, text-parsing

I'm trying to use Python to parse data from a text file which is formatted like this:

```
<event>  
A   0.8
B    0.4  0.3 -0.5  0.3
</event>
<event>  
A   0.2
B    0.3  0.2 -0.5  0.8
C    0.1  0.3 -0.3  0.2
C   -0.2  0.4 -0.1  0.9
</event>
<event>  
A   0.4
B    0.4  0.3 -0.5  0.3
C    0.3  0.7  0.6  0.5
</event>
```

Variables A & B are always present in each event, but as you can see, the C variable can occur up to two times in one event and sometimes doesn't occur at all. There are about 10,000+ events in total.

I'd like to format all of this so I can call each piece of data individually (i.e. column 2 for variable B from event 3), as well as in groups (i.e. plotting variable A, column 0 for all the events) but the repeating C variable is tripping me up a bit. I would ideally like to have a column of data for C variable #1 and C variable #2, where the data can simply be 0 when there is only one or zero C variables in an event.

My code is far from elegant at the moment and the output format isn't quite what it needs to be, so I'd love suggestions on how to simplify and improve this.

```
M = 10000        # number of events 
file = open('data.txt')
a_lines = open('a.txt','w')
b_lines = open('b.txt','w')
c1_lines = open('c1.txt','w')
c2_lines = open('c2.txt','w') 
c1 = []
c2 = []

for i in range(M):
    for line in file: 
        if not line.strip():
            continue  
        if line.startswith("</event>"):
            break 
        elif line.startswith("<event>"):
            a = file.next()
            print >>a_lines,i,a

for i in range(M):
    for line in file: 
        if line.startswith("B"):
            print >>b_lines,i,line.strip()
            nextline=file.next().strip()
            c1.append(nextline)
            nextline2=file.next().strip()
            c2.append(nextline2)
            break

# Parsing the duplicate C columns...
# I've formatted it so the 0 is aligned with the other data

for i in range(M):
    if "C" in c1[i]:
        print >>c1_lines, i, c1[i]
    else: 
        print >>c1_lines, i, "C    0" 


for i in range(M):
    if "C" in c2[i]:
        print >>c2_lines, i, c2[i]
    else: 
        print >>c2_lines, i, "C    0"

#  Sample variable formatting attempt: 

b_event_num,b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3=loadtxt("b.txt",usecols=(0,1,2,3,4),unpack=True)
b_0=array(b_0)
b_1=array(b_1)
b_2=array(b_2)
b_3=array(b_3)
b_0=b_0.reshape((len(b_0)),1)
b_1=b_1.reshape((len(b_1)),1)
b_2=b_2.reshape((len(b_2)),1)
b_3=b_3.reshape((len(b_3)),1)
b_points=np.hstack((b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3))
```

The extracted data itself looks okay, but when I try to load in the columns, I'm getting the following error, and I don't know why:

```
vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the output format you want? You want 2-dimensional lists for A, B and C? Do you need to create those files (a.txt, b.txt, etc) or are you creating them just to store the data?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for 2-d lists for A, B, and C. For example, for B, I'd have each event correspond to a row, and then the columns would be b_0, b_1, b_2, and b_3. That's what I was trying to do with b_points, at least. I'm creating the .txt files just because I've used loadtxt before and it seemed to do what I wanted. If there's an easier way to create a nicely-formatted output, I'd love to try it!

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific, I'm hoping to be able to say b[4][2] and get the b_2 data from the 4th event.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexError is coming from trying to access vals[0] when vals = [].  If you expand your code the error might make more sense:

```
vals = []
for i in usecols:
    vals[i] = i
```

The error happens in the first use of the loop because vals[0] isn't in the list.  I would suggest a fix, but I'm not sure what your trying to do.  If you just want vals to be the list [0,1,2,3,4] you can just use

```
vals = range(5)
```

Edit:
On a side note I don't think that saving it in a separate file is necessary.  It would be a lot better to just save it directly into the array, like:

```
M = 10000        # number of events 
file = open('data.txt')
a = []
b = []
c2 = []
c2 = []

def parseLine(line, section):
    line = line.split()
    line = line[1:]  # To take out the letter at the start
    section.append(line)

file.next()
for i in range(M):
    parseLine(file.next(), a)
    parseLine(file.next(), b)
    nextLine = file.next()
    if nextLine.startswith("C"):
        parseLine(nextLine, c1)
        nextLine = file.next()
        if nextLine.startswith("C"):
            parseLine(nextLine, c2)
            file.next()    # To get to the end of the event
        else:
            c2.append([0])
    else:
        c1.append([0])
        c2.append([0])
    file.next()
```

Be careful though because to get the element from the 2nd element from the 8th event for b you would do b[7][1], so it's b[event-1][column-1]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand -- so I should define `vals = range(5)` and then set `usecols=vals`?

Comment: I think I misunderstood when the problem was happening. Is the error occurring when the loadtxt() line is being called? I thought you were actually calling vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols].  If that's the case I'm not sure why the indexError is occuring, unless your calling it on the c data, in which some of the rows wouldn't have 5 columns and thus you would get an index out of range error.  Either way, I'm not sure why you are using unpack=True, if you don't then there is no need to reshape the data afterwards.